# How to search specific value in whole table column posgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a column name demo.

```
create table demo (
id int,
name varchar,
address varchar,
designation varchar
 );
```

I want to achieve the below scenario in one query

1. If I pass an empty string like "" then query will return all values in table
2. If I pass 'av' then query should match 'av' contins string in whole table column(name, address, designation);

Comment: I am using nodejs

Comment: Please include your Node JS code in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `WHERE` clause like this:

```
WHERE name LIKE '%av%' 
   OR address LIKE '%av%'
   OR designation LIKE '%av%'
```

Beware of SQL injection when you construct the search pattern.